# Carbon PHP parse datetime with dot notation

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm using Carbon 2 and am having an issue with some strange dates in my application that are given to me by a third party api, ideally they'd always be in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format but a few are coming in the following format: `YYYY.MM.DD`.

How can I use `Carbon::parse()` or PHP to reliably convert the string to hyphens and then parse it if in that format?

Example:

```php
echo Carbon::parse('2022.07.24 10:34:05');
```

This is invalid.

Maybe I just look for the dots and change to hyphen and try re-parsing?

Comment: Use the `createFromFormat()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [the documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation):

```php
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y.m.d H:i:s', '2022.07.24 10:34:05');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can normalize the string before the `parse()`:

```php
$str = '2022.07.24 10:34:05'; // or '2022-07-24 10:34:05'
echo Carbon::parse(strtr($str, ['.' => '-']));
```